# LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE is not working properly

Tags: mysql, database

this is my csv file

```
player_id,match_id,player,champion_id,ss1,ss2,position
9,10,1,19,Flash,Smite,JUNGLE
10,10,2,267,Exhaust,Flash,DUO_SUPPORT
11,10,3,119,Heal,Flash,DUO_CARRY
12,10,4,114,Teleport,Flash,TOP
13,10,5,112,Flash,Exhaust,MID
14,10,6,72,Smite,Flash,JUNGLE
15,10,7,3,Flash,Teleport,TOP
```

I use:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/downloads/participants.csv'
INTO TABLE participant
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

but the data are not loaded properly for example 
[the answer supposed to be 'JUNGLE' but instead only UNGLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbVya.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My theory is that this is a character encoding issue. This worked for me when I copy and pasted it into a new CSV.

It looks like it may have actually saved `|ungle`; not `ungle`.

To test this their, maybe open the CSV, delete the `J` and retype it manually.